# Backbone Memory Leak on very basic example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks, backbone-stickit

This is a simplified example of the projects I've worked on.

Everything is working properly but for some reason the memory usage increases, Some of the elements are not deleted from the DOM.

I have read many articles about Backbone memory leaks but it didn't help.

I'm using Backbone.stickit to model binding and I think this is causing the problem.

How should I fix this code for best memory performance? Check my sample code on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/najuwi/1/edit?html,js,output) and performance test video on [vimeo](https://vimeo.com/101634497)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.stickit/0.8.0/backbone.stickit.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Menu"></div>
    <ol id="Items"></ol>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var Data = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: "Default Title"
    },
});

var ItemForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<p>Your title: <%= title %></p><input name='title' value=<%= title %> /> <button name='close'>Close</button>"),
    events: {
        'click [name=close]':'closeEditForm'
    },
    bindings: {
        'input[name=title]': { 
            observe: 'title',
            events: ['blur']
        }
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model,'change',this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        this.stickit();
        return this;
    },
    closeEditForm: function () {
        // this.undelegateEvents();
        this.unstickit();
        this.remove();
        delete this.$el; // Delete the jQuery wrapped object variable
        delete this.el; // Delete the variable reference to this node  
    }
});

var Item = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template:  _.template("<%=title %> <button name='removeItem'>Remove</button> <button name='editItem'>Edit</button>"),
    events: {
        'click [name=removeItem]':'removeItem',
        'click [name=editItem]':'editItem'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model,'change',this.render);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        this.stickit();
        return this;
    },
    removeItem: function () {
        // this.undelegateEvents();
        this.unstickit();
        this.remove();
        delete this.$el; // Delete the jQuery wrapped object variable
        delete this.el; // Delete the variable reference to this node
    },
    editItem: function() {
        $('#main').append( new ItemForm({model: this.model }).render().el );
    }
});

var Menu = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#Menu',
    template: "<button name='add'>ADD NEW</button>",
    events: {
        'click [name=add]': '_add'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template );
        return this;
    },
    _add: function(){
        var item = new Item({
                model: new Data()
        });
        $('#Items').append( item.el );
    }
});
```